# on Interface or similar

Tags: c#, interface, serialization

I have an Interface as Contract. Now I'd like to define all Classes implementing the Interface as Serializable (XML).

What I'd like to do is something like follows:

```
public void DoSomethingWithElement( string element )
{
    IElement e = DeserializeElement(element);
}
```

void SerializeElement(IElement e)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IElement));
    Stream fStream = new MemoryStream();
    xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream, e);
    string element = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(fStream.GetBuffer());
    DoSomethingWithElement(element);
}

Is there a simple way for this? Maybe using Attributes?
If not, what do you propose: 
Not using an interface but maybe an abstract class? 
Implementing ISerializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract base class with the [Serializable] attribute is a very good choice, provided it suits your needs.  All classes that inherit from the base class will also be marked as serializable.

Keep in mind that the Serializable attribute just says "this class can be serialized" whereas implementing ISerializable (or IXmlSerializable) means "this class wants manual control over its serialization".  ISerializable isn't required for simple serialization.

**Update:** you could also consider writing a custom FxCop rule to generate warnings if a class implements your interface without being marked serializable.

If your abstract class *replaces* the interface then it will cover all grounds, but if you keep your interface seperate then there is still the potential for a class to implement the interface rather than inherit from the base-class--so having a way to detect these classes is still good.

Answer (score 0):

Because interfaces support inheritance, you should just be able to say:

```
interface IElement : ISerializable 
{
  // IElement specific items
}
```

That will ensure any class that implements `IElement` also implements `ISerializable`.

Comment: ISerializable is an option. But if I got the documentation right, I'd have to write the code for serialization. I was hoping there was an easier way. For example Attributes (which obviously is not working - at least not in a for me obvious way).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to decide if you're using XML Serialization or runtime serialization. XML Serialization does not use `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`.

XML Serialization will need to know the concrete types of all the classes you'll have implementing `IElement`. You do this with the `[XmlInclude]` attribute.

Comment: That one would also be a good idea, but it does not force the derived/implementing classes to do anything towards serialization.

Comment: There's no way to force them to do anything.